# VIM auto-complete plugin

Tags: vim

I roamed all over google searches

[Auto-complete vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169638/autocompletion-in-vim)

[Awesome JS Auto Completion - Vim](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CGsQFjAJ&url=http://tilvim.com/2013/08/21/js-autocomplete.html&ei=EFjCUoX1IcuIrAf3zIH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHp6gCWdVFD8A9Yh_dkWl5kjwKcAQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bmk)

[You complete me](http://val.markovic.io/blog/youcompleteme-a-fast-as-you-type-fuzzy-search-code-completion-engine-for-vim)

But none of them work for me.Can anyone please suggest me good js autocomplete plugin for vim editor

Comment: Do you mean that none of those plugins do what they are advertised to do when you install them, or do you mean that they do what they are supposed to do but that is not what you want? If the latter, then you need to explain what those plugins lack and what you mean by a "good JS autocomplete plugin".

Comment: @garyjohn OP failing to install these plugin.

Comment: @Pilot: If that's the case, then it would help if the OP would explain exactly what they did to install any one of them. Without knowing what they did wrong, it is difficult to know how to correct the problem.

Comment: The built in is pretty solid on it's own, enacted with `Ctrl+P`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> should do the job in vim.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) and a few others, but my hands-down favorite so far is [NeoComplCache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.vim) by Shougo. Easily the most full-fledged one I've tried so far.
PS: Mods hate questions like this, but they're still relevant.

Comment: I'd love to get more information; can you elaborate? what does NeoComplCache have that that the other ones don't?